# Bar chart is not being updated when "untick" the checkboxes in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, fetch-api

I have created a Bar chart in a react application. This chart is dynamic and by checking each checkbox a set of data needs to be uploaded.

Problem: data is being updated and displayed on the chart, however when I click on that specific checkbox nothing happens and chart does not get back to the original state. I tried Toggling the state of checkboxes but problem is still there and chart is not being updated.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

const RandomStatic = (props) => {
  let jsonData = [
    { gender: "female" },
    { gender: "male" },
    { gender: "female" },
    { gender: "male" },
    { gender: "female" },
    { gender: "male" },
    { gender: "female" },
    { gender: "female" },
    { gender: "female" },
    { gender: "female" },
  ];

  const [userFemaleCounter, setUserFemaleCounter] = useState();

  const [userMaleCounter, setUserMaleCounter] = useState();

  const [totalCounter, setTotalCounter] = useState();

  const [femalePercentage, setFemalePercentage] = useState();

  const [malePercentage, setMalePercentage] = useState();

  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(jsonData);

  const [femaleIsChecked, setFemaleIsChecked] = useState(false);

  const [maleIsChecked, setMaleIsChecked] = useState(false);



 useEffect(() => {

    // Getting all Data in an array
    let allData = jsonData.map(function (e) {

      return e.gender;

    });
console.log(allData);
// Display Gender data on the chart
let fCounter = [];
let mCounter = [];
allData.forEach((gender) => {
  if (gender === "female") {
    fCounter = ++fCounter;
  } else if (gender === "male") {
    mCounter = ++mCounter;
  }
});


let userFemaleCounter = fCounter;
setUserFemaleCounter(fCounter);
console.log(userFemaleCounter);

let userMaleCounter = mCounter;
setUserMaleCounter(mCounter);
console.log(userMaleCounter);

let totalCounter = fCounter + mCounter;
setTotalCounter(totalCounter);
console.log(totalCounter);

let femalePercentage = (fCounter / totalCounter) * 100;
setFemalePercentage(femalePercentage);

let malePercentage = (mCounter / totalCounter) * 100;
setMalePercentage(malePercentage);


}, [chartData]);

useEffect(() => {
    ///change the jsonData
    //setChartData
    let allData = chartData.map(function (e) {
      return e.gender;
    });
    let mCounter = [];
    let fCounter = [];
    allData.forEach((gender) => {
      if (gender === "female") {
        fCounter = ++fCounter;
      } else if (gender === "male") {
        mCounter = ++mCounter;
      }
    });

 let totalCounter = fCounter + mCounter;
    setTotalCounter(totalCounter);

let userFemaleCounter = fCounter;
setUserFemaleCounter(userFemaleCounter);
let femalePercentage = (fCounter / totalCounter) * 100;
setFemalePercentage(femalePercentage);
let userMaleCounter = 0;
setUserMaleCounter(userMaleCounter);
let malePercentage = 0;
setMalePercentage(malePercentage);



}, [femaleIsChecked]);




//useeffect for MALE checkbox
  useEffect(() => {



let allData = jsonData.map(function (e) {
  return e.gender;
});
let mCounter = [];
let fCounter = [];
allData.forEach((gender) => {
  if (gender === "female") {
    fCounter = ++fCounter;
  } else if (gender === "male") {
    mCounter = ++mCounter;
  }
});

let totalCounter = fCounter + mCounter;
setTotalCounter(totalCounter);

let malePercentage = (mCounter / totalCounter) * 100;
setMalePercentage(malePercentage);

fCounter = [];
let femalePercentage = [];
setFemalePercentage(femalePercentage);


}, [maleIsChecked]);





const toggleFemale = () => {
  
    if(femaleIsChecked == true)
    {
      setFemaleIsChecked(false)
    }else{
      setFemaleIsChecked(true)
    }
    
  }


 const toggleMale = () => setMaleIsChecked(chartData)
  const toggleAll = () => setChartData(!chartData)
  //console.log(toggleFemale)



return (
    <div>
      <Bar
        className="chart"
        data={{
          labels: ["Female", "Male"],
          datasets: [
            {
              data: [femalePercentage, malePercentage],
              backgroundColor: ["green", "yellow"],
              borderColor: ["green", "yellow"],
              borderWidth: 0.5,
            },
          ],
        }}
    options={{
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      plugins: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Male and Female Ratio",
        },
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
      scales: {
        y: {
          display: true,
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Percentage",
          },
        },
        x: {
          display: true,
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Population",
          },
        },
      },
      showTooltips: false,
      hover: false,
    }}
  />
  <div className="checkbox-form-wrapper">
    <div className="chartBox">
      <label>Female Only</label>
      <input
        name="femalePercentage"
        type="checkbox"
        //checked={femaleIsChecked}
        onChange={toggleFemale}
      />
      <label>Male Only</label>
      <input
        name="malePercentage"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={maleIsChecked}
        onChange={toggleMale}
        
      />
      <label>Both Female and Male</label>
      <input
        name="chartData"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={chartData}
        onChange={toggleAll}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


 );
};

export default RandomStatic;
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the code above work as you would expect it, the main changes needed are:

1. add guards in each Effect to run only when that flag is true. Example for **maleIsChecked**:

   if(!maleIsChecked) { return; }
2. for the **Effect displaying both**, make sure it runs only if both flags are off:

   if(femaleIsChecked || maleIsChecked) { return;}

   **and that it runs on every change**

   useEffect(() => { ... }, [chartData, maleIsChecked, femaleIsChecked]):
3. update **toggle functions** to switch "correctly". Example for toggleMale:

   const toggleMale = () => setMaleIsChecked(!maleIsChecked)

However, I strongly recommend to **switch the approach from checkboxes to radio buttons**. For me, this seems more natural as interaction, because you have all the options "on the table" and they are mutually exclusive. Working code suggested below, changes highlighted with CHANGE:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

// CHANGE: define an enum to handle data types to be displayed
const TypesOfDataToDisplay = {
    MALE: 'male',
    FEMALE: 'female',
    BOTH: 'both'
}

const RandomStatic = (props) => {
  let jsonData = [
    { gender: "female" },
    { gender: "male" },
    { gender: "female" },
    { gender: "male" },
    { gender: "female" },
    { gender: "male" },
    { gender: "female" },
    { gender: "female" },
    { gender: "female" },
    { gender: "female" },
  ];

  const [userFemaleCounter, setUserFemaleCounter] = useState();

  const [userMaleCounter, setUserMaleCounter] = useState();

  const [totalCounter, setTotalCounter] = useState();

  const [femalePercentage, setFemalePercentage] = useState();

  const [malePercentage, setMalePercentage] = useState();

  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(jsonData);

  // CHANGE: define a new state that indicates data type to be displayed
  const [dataToDisplay, setDataToDisplay] = useState(TypesOfDataToDisplay.BOTH);

  // CHANGE: remove boolean states (using them, for each toggle you will generate two renderings)
  //const [femaleIsChecked, setFemaleIsChecked] = useState(false);
  //const [maleIsChecked, setMaleIsChecked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    // CHANGE: skip this effect if not needed
    if(dataToDisplay !== TypesOfDataToDisplay.BOTH) {
        return;
    }

    // Getting all Data in an array
    let allData = jsonData.map(function (e) {

      return e.gender;

    });
    console.log(allData);
    // Display Gender data on the chart
    let fCounter = [];
    let mCounter = [];
    allData.forEach((gender) => {
      if (gender === "female") {
        fCounter = ++fCounter;
      } else if (gender === "male") {
        mCounter = ++mCounter;
      }
    });


    let userFemaleCounter = fCounter;
    setUserFemaleCounter(fCounter);
    console.log(userFemaleCounter);

    let userMaleCounter = mCounter;
    setUserMaleCounter(mCounter);
    console.log(userMaleCounter);

    let totalCounter = fCounter + mCounter;
    setTotalCounter(totalCounter);
    console.log(totalCounter);

    let femalePercentage = (fCounter / totalCounter) * 100;
    setFemalePercentage(femalePercentage);

    let malePercentage = (mCounter / totalCounter) * 100;
    setMalePercentage(malePercentage);


  }, [chartData, dataToDisplay]); // CHANGE: make sure the effect is called on data type change

  useEffect(() => {

    // CHANGE: skip this effect if not needed
    if(dataToDisplay !== TypesOfDataToDisplay.FEMALE) {
        return;
    }

    ///change the jsonData
    //setChartData
    let allData = chartData.map(function (e) {
      return e.gender;
    });
    let mCounter = [];
    let fCounter = [];
    allData.forEach((gender) => {
      if (gender === "female") {
        fCounter = ++fCounter;
      } else if (gender === "male") {
        mCounter = ++mCounter;
      }
    });

    let totalCounter = fCounter + mCounter;
    setTotalCounter(totalCounter);

    let userFemaleCounter = fCounter;
    setUserFemaleCounter(userFemaleCounter);
    let femalePercentage = (fCounter / totalCounter) * 100;
    setFemalePercentage(femalePercentage);
    let userMaleCounter = 0;
    setUserMaleCounter(userMaleCounter);
    let malePercentage = 0;
    setMalePercentage(malePercentage);



  }, [dataToDisplay]); // CHANGE: make sure the effect is called on data type change




  //useeffect for MALE checkbox
  useEffect(() => {

    // CHANGE: skip this effect if not needed
    if(dataToDisplay !== TypesOfDataToDisplay.MALE) {
        return;
    }

    let allData = jsonData.map(function (e) {
      return e.gender;
    });
    let mCounter = [];
    let fCounter = [];
    allData.forEach((gender) => {
      if (gender === "female") {
        fCounter = ++fCounter;
      } else if (gender === "male") {
        mCounter = ++mCounter;
      }
    });

    let totalCounter = fCounter + mCounter;
    setTotalCounter(totalCounter);

    let malePercentage = (mCounter / totalCounter) * 100;
    setMalePercentage(malePercentage);

    fCounter = [];
    let femalePercentage = [];
    setFemalePercentage(femalePercentage);


  }, [dataToDisplay]); // CHANGE: make sure the effect is called on data type change

  // CHANGE: remove togglers for the boolean states
  /*const toggleFemale = () => {
  
    if(femaleIsChecked == true)
    {
      setFemaleIsChecked(false)
    }else{
      setFemaleIsChecked(true)
    }
    
  }


 const toggleMale = () => setMaleIsChecked(chartData)
  const toggleAll = () => setChartData(!chartData)*/

// CHANGE: add only one handler for changing data to be displayed
const toggleDisplay = (event) => {
    setDataToDisplay(event.currentTarget.value);
}

    // CHANGE: switch from checkboxes to radio buttons and update definitions with new handler
  return (
    <div className="chartContainer">
      <Bar
        className="chart"
        data={{
          labels: ["Female", "Male"],
          datasets: [
            {
              data: [femalePercentage, malePercentage],
              backgroundColor: ["green", "yellow"],
              borderColor: ["green", "yellow"],
              borderWidth: 0.5,
            },
          ],
        }}
        options={{
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          plugins: {
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: "Male and Female Ratio",
            },
            legend: {
              display: false,
            },
          },
          scales: {
            y: {
              display: true,
              title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Percentage",
              },
            },
            x: {
              display: true,
              title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Population",
              },
            },
          },
          showTooltips: false,
          hover: false,
        }}
      />
      <div className="checkbox-form-wrapper">
        <div className="chartBox">
          <label>Female Only</label>
          <input
            name="femalePercentage"
            type="radio"
            value={TypesOfDataToDisplay.FEMALE}
            checked={dataToDisplay === TypesOfDataToDisplay.FEMALE}
            onChange={toggleDisplay}
          />
          <label>Male Only</label>
          <input
            name="malePercentage"
            type="radio"
            value={TypesOfDataToDisplay.MALE}
            checked={dataToDisplay === TypesOfDataToDisplay.MALE}
            onChange={toggleDisplay}

          />
          <label>Both Female and Male</label>
          <input
            name="chartData"
            type="radio"
            value={TypesOfDataToDisplay.BOTH}
            checked={dataToDisplay === TypesOfDataToDisplay.BOTH}
            onChange={toggleDisplay}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  );
};

export default RandomStatic;
```